# Running two Drupal sites off the same database: Is it possible?

Tags: 7

Is it possible point a second Drupal site to an existing Drupal database, if that second site is only used to browse the content, no logins, registrations or content add/edit/deletes?

Comment: When you run install.php, it tells you when the database you are using contains already tables. I tried using the same database for two different sub-domains, but the installer didn't allow me that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. Should you do it? Probably not.

Using [table prefixes](http://drupal.org/node/2622), you can run two completely separate sites with table names like "site1_node" and "site2_node", so they don't collide. In your case, it sounds like maybe you also want to share data between the sites?

On solution to that, is to share tables between these two, but I strongly recommend *against* that. I've tried it on two different sites, and I've mostly gotten bit badly by it. Use [Domain](http://drupal.org/project/domain) instead, to run two domains from a single Drupal install.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly possible. Look for instructions about multisite installations combined with the domain module. Both sites can have common and separate settings, and both sites can have write access.

To set-up everything, you also need to configure your DNS settings and your server settings appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it, but I think that you can use two different databases which replicate with each-other. I think that this may be a better option than using the same database for two different sites. Master-slave replication in MySQL is very easy and it can be managed from phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are able to maintain multiple sites with single drupal installation. Please check this article: [How to install multiple domains in a single Drupal installation](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3686/how-to-install-multiple-domains-in-a-single-drupal-installation).